# Alternatives to directly assigning Vectors in Unity, C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a 2d game in Unity with a portal system, think Valve's portal series. When objects fall down into a portal, and the other side of the portal is pointing right, I want them spat out to the right. I've built something to make this happen -

```
    public Vector2 ConvertVelocity(Vector2 initialVelocity) 
    {
        Quaternion conversion = Quaternion.FromToRotation(inPortal.transform.right, -outPortal.transform.right);
        Vector2 newVelocity = conversion * initialVelocity;
        Debug.Log("ConvertVelocity Triggered");
        return newVelocity;
    }
```

This works fine to 'rotate' the vectors of most objects, but my player object has a movement script that interferes with this process.

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Variables
        isGreenActivated = outPortal.GetComponent<Portal>().activated; 

       
        if (isGreenActivated)
        {
            Vector2 ForceApplied = ConvertVelocity(rb.velocity);
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            rb.AddForce(ForceApplied, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        
        if (!isGreenActivated)
        {
            Vector2 playerMovement = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            rb.velocity = (playerMovement);
        }
    }
```

My player movement works by assigning the vector to what my horizontal input * speed equals, and then rb.velocity.y, which is altered by some jump stuff I have.

When the portal is activated, I want ConvertVelocity() to be AddForce()'d to my players rigidbody, this works for a split second until the assigned vector I have, playerMovement, resets my players velocity back to it's terms.

My assigned vector is overriding the AddForce() I'm trying to apply to my player object's vector, however, I've yet to find a way to fix this.

I've tried having my movement work through AddForce also, via

```
        if (!isGreenActivated)
        {
            Vector2 playerMovement = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            rb.AddForce(playerMovement - rb.velocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
```

Though this also overrides my other AddForce() for the vector conversion. If I AddForce() without subtracting playerMovement by rb.velocity, my player object speeds up to oblivion.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: In your solution attempt you should have used `ForceMode2D.Force` instead of `ForceMode2D.Impulse`. Former is intended for acceleration, like walking and latter for one time explosive forces, like jumping or explosions. It probably won't be much of a help, since it dramatically reduces responsiveness and will feel of in your game.

Comment: The question might have a bad premise. From what I understand you're basically experiencing a "mirror" portal where you enter moving to the right and reemerge moving left, but since you're holding the right key you instantly go back and are stuck in limbo. The actual question should be: How do you want your character to behave in such a case?

Comment: I would say either have a kid of cool-down after using a portal where your input is ignored - or pass along the orientation change and apply the same delta rotation also to your forces

Comment: Thanks everyone, my movement still works on assigning the vector, but I found out about 'states', and now have my char in different states that operate on different code depending on if theyve just been spat out the portal. In essence, I turn off movement after being spat out the portal.